# Display Selected Option (different href) in Dropdown Title

Tags: php, laravel, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, dropdown

Im working on my Laravel project, and i wanna make some filter buttons for my data table.

Those buttons look like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swpbw.png

I want to display the selected option in dropdown title. For example, the `Author` title should be changed to any others name like `Admin` or `User` etc... after selecting the option from the dropdown button.

**Author Dropdown Button (original) :**

```
<div class="dropdown">

    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle mr-2" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Author
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/posts?user_id={{$user->id}}">
                {{ $user->name }}
            </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>

</div>
```

I found some solutions, they all look like this :

```
$(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'a', function(){
    $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
});
```

**But the problem is :**

The solution above only works if the `href` (url) from `dropdown-menu` is fixed (`href="#"`).

In my project, those dropdowns have different href, so the title can only be changed for a short moment after clicked, then back to default after the url changed.

I think we need to catch the url then make some conditions to display the correct title.

For example, my `Category` filter only have 3 fixed options so i can do it like this.

**Category Dropdown Button :**

```
@php
    $request = Request::getRequestUri();
@endphp

<div class="dropdown">

    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle mr-2" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        @switch(true)

            @case(strstr($request, 'category_id=1'))
                Pc
                @break

            @case(strstr($request, 'category_id=2'))
                Console
                @break

            @case(strstr($request, 'category_id=3'))
                Handheld
                @break

            @default
                Category

        @endswitch
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="{{strstr($request, 'category_id=1') ? 'dropdown-item active' : 'dropdown-item'}}" href="/posts?category_id=1">
            Pc
        </a>
        <a class="{{strstr($request, 'category_id=2') ? 'dropdown-item active' : 'dropdown-item'}}" href="/posts?category_id=2">
            Console
        </a>
        <a class="{{strstr($request, 'category_id=3') ? 'dropdown-item active' : 'dropdown-item'}}" href="/posts?category_id=3">
            Handheld
        </a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Meanwhile, i have a `foreach` loop in the `Author` filter, cause the number of users is not fixed. So i cannot use the same code like i did with `Category`.

I had tried this but it just doesn't work.

**Author Dropdown Button (not working) :**

```
<div class="dropdown">

    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle mr-2" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        @if($request == '/posts' OR strstr($request, 'posts?page='))
            Author
        @else
            @foreach($users as $user)
                @if(strstr($request, 'user_id={{$user->id}}'))
                    {{ $user->name }}
                @endif
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/posts?user_id={{$user->id}}">
                {{ $user->name }}
            </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>

</div>
```

It cannot display the user name on title when clicked (blank result).

I also tried this one, but not working either.

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    @if($request == "/posts?user_id={{$user->id}}"))
        {{ $user->name }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Please help guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution.

The `if` condition (inside the `foreach`) is right, but somehow it doesn't work in blade template.

So, just put it in the php section.

**Author Dropdown Button (working) :**

```
<div class="dropdown">

    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm dropdown-toggle mr-2" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        @if($request == '/posts'
            OR strstr($request, 'posts?search=') 
            OR strstr($request, 'posts?page='))
            Author
        @else
            @foreach($users as $user)
                @php
                    if(strstr($request, 'user_id='.$user->id)){
                        echo $user->name;
                    }
                @endphp
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </button>

    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        @foreach($users as $user)
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="/posts?user_id={{$user->id}}">
                {{ $user->name }}
            </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you still can use the JS solution by preventing the redirection of the link

```
$(".dropdown-menu").on('click', 'a', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
    $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work bro. Only the button title changed, but it prevents the url to change so the filter function now is broken.